# Dynamic web project error in eclipse neon.2 when deploying

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, tomcat, cxf

I am using eclipse neon.2. I am trying to deploy a web app using tomcat 8.0 which uses RESTful web services and CXF library. I have successfully deployed the same application to another computer that I have which uses linux but I am trying to do the same in my laptop and I get these error.

```
May 12, 2017 12:48:27 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext 
listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener 
instance of class 
org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error 
creating bean with name 'base': Invocation of init method failed; 
nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not 
initialize class com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.Utils
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1572)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:434)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4853)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class 
com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.Utils
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.<init>(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:92)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:444)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:292)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:139)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1138)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:162)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:247)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:234)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:441)
at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:641)
at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache$2.run(JAXBContextCache.java:344)
at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache$2.run(JAXBContextCache.java:342)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache.createContext(JAXBContextCache.java:342)
at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache.getCachedContextAndSchemas(JAXBContextCache.java:243)
at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache.getCachedContextAndSchemas(JAXBContextCache.java:165)
at org.apache.cxf.ws.discovery.internal.WSDiscoveryServiceImpl$WSDiscoveryProvider.<init>(WSDiscoveryServiceImpl.java:443)
at org.apache.cxf.ws.discovery.internal.WSDiscoveryServiceImpl.startup(WSDiscoveryServiceImpl.java:246)
at org.apache.cxf.ws.discovery.internal.WSDiscoveryServiceImpl.serverStarted(WSDiscoveryServiceImpl.java:154)
at org.apache.cxf.ws.discovery.listeners.WSDiscoveryServerListener.startServer(WSDiscoveryServerListener.java:73)
at org.apache.cxf.bus.managers.ServerLifeCycleManagerImpl.startServer(ServerLifeCycleManagerImpl.java:61)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:137)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean.create(JAXRSServerFactoryBean.java:206)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1700)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1639)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1568)
```

Also, my web.xml file is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
<display-name>JSONExample</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
<description>Apache CXF Endpoint</description>
<display-name>cxf</display-name>
<servlet-name>cxf</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>cxf</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
<session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
</session-config>
<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>WEB-INF/cxf-beans.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
</web-app>
```

And the cxf-beans.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws" 
xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd 
http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws 
http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd 
http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs 
http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd">
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
<bean id="Users" class="rest.UserEndpoint" />
<jaxrs:server id="base" address="/">    
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="Users"/>
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    <jaxrs:providers>
        <!-- bean class="utilities.CustomJSONProvider"/-->
        <bean class="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider"/>
    </jaxrs:providers>
  </jaxrs:server>
  </beans>
```

Any help will be higly appreciated.

Comment: Did you use maven or not? The problem is you are missing the library of `com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.Utils`. If you using maven, let's try `mvn install` to download and build your project, if it's not a maven project, let's download the lib, add to your buildpath

Comment: No I am not using maven. Yes I have tried to import some jaxb-impl.jar but the problem persists. Where can I find the library that is missing ;